# Function calls and varagrs

Tags: python, python-3.x

`def func(a, b, c, d): print(a, b, c, d)`

```
func(1, c=3, *(2,), **{'d':4})
func(1, c=3, 2, **{'d':4})
```

Why does the former call work but the latter not? I mean shouldn't the first return an error too? Doesn't * simply unpack an iterable?

Comment: That surprises me.  No positional arguments are allowed to appear after keyword arguments....

Comment: In Python3.4, they both give me syntax errors.

Comment: I tried in 3.2 abd 3.2

Comment: Interetsingly, func(1, c=3, *(2,), **{'d':4}) does work, which shouldn't either.

Comment: Sorry exactly, i edited the qeustion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls) say:

> If the syntax `*expression` appears in the function call, `expression` must evaluate to an iterable. Elements from this iterable are treated as if they were additional positional arguments; if there are positional arguments *x1, ..., xN*, and expression evaluates to a sequence *y1, ..., yM*, this is equivalent to a call with M+N positional arguments *x1, ..., xN, y1, ..., yM*.
>
> **A consequence of this is that although the `*expression` syntax may appear after some keyword arguments, it is processed before the keyword arguments…**

---

At lot of people are confused by the fact that function definitions have a similar, sometimes misleadingly-similar, syntax.

In a function definition, a variable-argument parameter (like `*args`) comes before any the keyword-only parameters. Of course being keyword-only and having a default value are completely independent, but it's pretty common that the keyword-only parameters all have default values. So, the syntax often looks like `def func(a, *args, c=4, **kwargs):`. Which can lead you to expect `func(1, *(2,), c=3, **{'d': 4}` to be the matching call syntax, even though it isn't. Just remember that `def func(a=1, *args, c, **kwargs)` is perfectly legal, and it still makes `a` a positional-or-keyword parameter and `c` a keyword-only parameter.

---

If you're interested how this works specifically in CPython (although other implementations are probably all pretty similar):

The function call itself gets compiled to pass the value of the `expression` on the stack, still separate from the normal arguments. It's inside the interpreter, in the function-call evaluator, where the stack frame for the function body's execution gets built, where that value is exploded into extra arguments.

---

It may help to see how CPython parses and compiles this code:

```
>>> astpp(ast.parse("func(1, c=3, *(2,), **{'d':4})"))
Module(
  body=[
    Expr(
      value=Call(
        func=Name(id='func', ctx=Load()), 
        args=[Num(n=1)], 
        keywords=[keyword(arg='c', value=Num(n=3))], 
        starargs=Tuple(elts=[Num(n=2)], ctx=Load()), 
        kwargs=Dict(keys=[Str(s='d')], values=[Num(n=4)])))])"
```

Even if you don't understand ASTs, you should be able to see that the `(2,)` is still separate at parse time, stored in a field named `starargs`.

This gets compiled to this bytecode:

```
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (func)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('c')
              9 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             12 LOAD_CONST               7 ((2,))
             15 BUILD_MAP                1
             18 LOAD_CONST               5 (4)
             21 LOAD_CONST               6 ('d')
             24 STORE_MAP
             25 CALL_FUNCTION_VAR_KW   257
             28 POP_TOP
             29 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
```

You probably don't understand all that gibberish, but you can see that the tuple `(2,)` is being loaded onto the stack at offset 12, and it's still on the stack when the opcode [`CALL_FUNCTION_VAR_KW`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION_VAR_KW) gets executed. And you can look that opcode up in the docs, where it says:

> Calls a function. `argc` is interpreted as in `CALL_FUNCTION`. The top element on the stack contains the keyword arguments dictionary, followed by the variable-arguments tuple, followed by explicit keyword and positional arguments.

So, the "variable-arguments tuple" is still separate.

Answer (score 5):

Positional parameters must always appear before named and unpacked parameters.

In the expression:

```
func(1, c=3, 2, **{'d':4})
```

The `2` is a positional parameter while `c=3` is a named parameter.  It is invalid written this way.  You have to move the named parameter after *all* positional parameters.

```
func(1, 2, c=3, **{'d':4})
```

---

On the other hand, the expression:

```
func(1, c=3, *(2,), **{'d':4})
```

is valid.  `1` is the only positional parameter here.  `c=3` is a named parameter and `*(2,)` and `**{'d':4}` are unpacked.  It's all valid as long as the positional parameter comes first.

Comment: I added an explanation for why the first works. The positional parameters must always come first.

Comment: But aren't objects in * assigned by position?

Comment: Sure, but they are interpreted as following all positional parameters. So `foo(1, *(2, 3, 4))` is exactly the same as if you had done `foo(1, 2, 3, 4)` or even `foo(*(1, 2, 3, 4))`.

Comment: But because first there is `c=3` shouldn't I get an error? Then why `func(1, c=3, **{'d':4}, *(2,)) doesnt work?

Comment: The `c=3` is fine where it is.  The order of the named parameters and unpacked parameters generally doesn't matter.  The only exception is that unpacked named parameters must appear at the end.